# POST array of data in the API

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new here and need your help guys.

I want to POST this array of data in the API.

Here's my code:

Order.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let orderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    order_details: {
      type: [String],
    },
    total: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  {
    collection: 'orders',
  },
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

post.route.js

```
const express = require('express');

const postRoute = express.Router();

let OrderModel = require('../models/Order');

//create order

postRoute.route('/order').post((req, res, next) => {
  OrderModel.create(req.body, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      res.json(data);
    }
  });
});
```

---

When I check my **localhost:4000/api/order** it only display the **TOTAL** but not the **ORDER_DETAILS** it was empty. Like this.

```
[{"order_details":[], "total":395,"__v":0}
```

I know I missed something here and I don't know how to solve it. There is no error or anything. Just the ORDER_DETAILS array are empty. It has a data in the browser all I need is to store ORDER_DETAILS to the API. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's regarding Your request body. Try to log the request body and check. I'm pretty sure that `order_details` is wrong in the `req.body`.
Add the

```
console.log('Request Body: ', req.body)
```

before calling the OrderModel.create function.

Comment: Hi, @CyberEternal. There is nothing wrong in the console request body, it actually has data in it. I was able to solve it by changing the order_details type schema. I changed the type [String] to Array. If [String] it only display just the ID's of the array not all the data but if I choose the type Array, it displays all details like their product_name and price, etc. Anyways with your comment I was enlightened. Thank you very much.